# Float Values Rounding with SQLAlchemy and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

My question is similar to this unanswered question: [SQLAlchemy commits makes float to be rounded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499787/sqlalchemy-commits-makes-float-to-be-rounded)

I have a text file of data that looks like this:

```
#file camera date mjd focus error
ibcy02blq UVIS1 08/03/09   55046.196630   0.57857   0.55440
ibcy02bnq UVIS1 08/03/09   55046.198330  -0.15000   0.42111
ibcy03j8q UVIS1 08/11/09   55054.041650  -0.37143   0.40802
ibcy03jaq UVIS1 08/11/09   55054.043350  -0.91857   0.51859
ibcy04m4q UVIS1 08/18/09   55061.154900  -0.32333   0.52327
ibcy04m6q UVIS1 08/18/09   55061.156600  -0.24867   0.66651
ibcy05b7q UVIS1 09/05/09   55079.912670   0.64900   0.58423
ibcy05b9q UVIS1 09/05/09   55079.914370   0.82000   0.50202
ibcy06meq UVIS1 10/02/09   55106.909840  -0.09667   0.24016
```

But once I read it into my MySQL database it looks like this:

```
+------+-----------+--------+------------+---------+----------+
| id   | filename  | camera | date       | mjd     | focus    |
+------+-----------+--------+------------+---------+----------+
| 1026 | ibcy02blq | UVIS1  | 2009-08-03 | 55046.2 |  0.57857 |
| 1027 | ibcy02bnq | UVIS1  | 2009-08-03 | 55046.2 |    -0.15 |
| 1028 | ibcy03j8q | UVIS1  | 2009-08-11 |   55054 | -0.37143 |
| 1029 | ibcy03jaq | UVIS1  | 2009-08-11 |   55054 | -0.91857 |
| 1030 | ibcy04m4q | UVIS1  | 2009-08-18 | 55061.2 | -0.32333 |
| 1031 | ibcy04m6q | UVIS1  | 2009-08-18 | 55061.2 | -0.24867 |
| 1032 | ibcy05b7q | UVIS1  | 2009-09-05 | 55079.9 |    0.649 |
| 1033 | ibcy05b9q | UVIS1  | 2009-09-05 | 55079.9 |     0.82 |
| 1034 | ibcy06meq | UVIS1  | 2009-10-02 | 55106.9 | -0.09667 |
| 1035 | ibcy06mgq | UVIS1  | 2009-10-02 | 55106.9 |  -0.1425 |
+------+-----------+--------+------------+---------+----------+
```

The `mjd` column is being truncated and I'm not sure why. I understand that there are floating point precision errors for something like 1/3 but this looks more like some type of rounding is being implemented.

Here is the code I use to ingest the data into the database:

```
def make_focus_table_main():
    """The main controller for the make_focus_table 
    module."""
    logging.info('Process Starting')
    filename_list = glob.glob('/grp/hst/OTA/focus/source/FocusModel/UVIS*FocusHistory.txt')
    logging.info('Found {} files'.format(len(filename_list)))
    for filename in filename_list:
        logging.info('Reading data from {}'.format(filename))
        output_list = []
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            data = f.readlines()
            for line in data[1:]:
                line = line.split()
                output_dict = {}
                output_dict['filename'] = line[0]
                output_dict['camera'] = line[1]
                output_dict['date'] = datetime.strptime(line[2], '%m/%d/%y')
                output_dict['mjd'] = float(line[3])
                output_dict['focus'] = float(line[4])
                output_list.append(output_dict)
        logging.info('Beginning bulk insert of records.')
        engine.execute(Focus.__table__.insert(), output_list)
        logging.info('Database insert complete.')
    logging.info('Process Complete')
```

I've used pdb to check that the values are not being truncated prior to being passed to the database (i.e. Python/SQLAlchemy is not performing the rounding). I can verify this in the `INSERT` command SQLAlchemy issues:

```
2014-04-11 13:08:20,522 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO focus (filename, camera, date, mjd, focus) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
2014-04-11 13:08:20,602 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (
    ('ibcy02blq', 'UVIS2', datetime.datetime(2009, 8, 3, 0, 0), 55046.19663, 1.05778), 
    ('ibcy02bnq', 'UVIS2', datetime.datetime(2009, 8, 3, 0, 0), 55046.19833, 1.32333), 
    ('ibcy03j8q', 'UVIS2', datetime.datetime(2009, 8, 11, 0, 0), 55054.04165, 1.57333), 
    ('ibcy03jaq', 'UVIS2', datetime.datetime(2009, 8, 11, 0, 0), 55054.04335, 0.54333), 
    ('ibcy04m4q', 'UVIS2', datetime.datetime(2009, 8, 18, 0, 0), 55061.1549, -1.152), 
    ('ibcy04m6q', 'UVIS2', datetime.datetime(2009, 8, 18, 0, 0), 55061.1566, -1.20733), 
    ('ibcy05b7q', 'UVIS2', datetime.datetime(2009, 9, 5, 0, 0), 55079.91267, 2.35905), 
    ('ibcy05b9q', 'UVIS2', datetime.datetime(2009, 9, 5, 0, 0), 55079.91437, 1.84524)  
    ... displaying 10 of 1025 total bound parameter sets ...  
    ('ichl05qwq', 'UVIS2', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 2, 0, 0), 56749.05103, -2.98), 
    ('ichl05qxq', 'UVIS2', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 2, 0, 0), 56749.05177, -3.07))
2014-04-11 13:08:20,959 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

Here is how the column is defined in my SQLAlchemy classes:

```
class Focus(Base):
    """ORM for the table storing the focus measurement information."""
    __tablename__ = 'focus'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    filename = Column(String(17), index=True, nullable=False)
    camera = Column(String(5), index=True, nullable=False)
    date = Column(Date(), index=True, nullable=False)
    mjd = Column(Float(precision=20, scale=10), index=True, nullable=False)
    focus = Column(Float(15), nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('filename', 'camera', 
                      name='focus_uniqueness_constraint'),)
```

Here is the SQL that's logged from SQLAlchemy with `echo=True` when I create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE focus (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    filename VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL, 
    camera VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
    date DATE NOT NULL, 
    mjd FLOAT(20) NOT NULL, 
    focus FLOAT(15) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    CONSTRAINT focus_uniqueness_constraint UNIQUE (filename, camera)
)
```

So far, so good. But here's what I see MySQL with a `SHOW CREATE TABLE focus;`:

```
CREATE TABLE `focus` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filename` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `camera` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `mjd` float NOT NULL,
  `focus` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `focus_uniqueness_constraint` (`filename`,`camera`),
  KEY `ix_focus_filename` (`filename`),
  KEY `ix_focus_mjd` (`mjd`),
  KEY `ix_focus_date` (`date`),
  KEY `ix_focus_camera` (`camera`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1193 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Somehow the `FLOAT` definition changed! Is this some type of MySQL configuration setting? I'm just running this on my local host right now, but if this is a configuration setting I'm concerned about the portability of this code onto a production server if I continue to use floats. I could just switch to a decimal column type as I've seen in other SO questions since I need exact values but I would like to understand what's going on here.

---

**Update**: Just to expand a little on two-bit-alchemist's answer, here is how it changes my query:

```
> SELECT ROUND(mjd,10) FROM focus LIMIT 10;
+------------------+
| ROUND(mjd,10)    |
+------------------+
| 55046.1953125000 |
| 55046.1992187500 |
| 55054.0429687500 |
| 55054.0429687500 |
| 55061.1562500000 |
| 55061.1562500000 |
| 55079.9140625000 |
| 55079.9140625000 |
| 55106.9101562500 |
| 55106.9101562500 |
+------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice that all the decimal precision is still there. I had no idea `SELECT` was rounding values but I guess this makes sense if you think about how a floating point representation works. It uses the full bytes allocated for that number, how many decimals you display is arbitrary up to the full length of the float:https://stackoverflow.com/a/20482699/1216837

Specifying the precision only seems to affect if it's stored as a double or a single: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html.

But, what's also interesting/annoying is that I have to worry about this same thing when issuing a `SELECT` from the SQLAlchemy layer:

```
query = psf_session.query(Focus).first()
print query.filename, query.mjd, query.focus
```

Gives me `bcy02blq 55046.2 1.05778` so the values are still being rounded. Again, this makes sense because SQLAlchemy is just issuing SQL commands anyway. All in all this is motivating me to switch to a `DECIMAL` column type: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html

Comment: Are you sure the definition changed? I'm not familiar enough with MySQL's implementation to know by just looking at this, but I wouldn't assume from this that it had changed. I assume that MySQL for whatever reason only gives you 6 significant digits when you `SELECT` a `float` column, and to get a different value you need to `ROUND` to a different number of digits.

Comment: How do you "read" the data into the database? Using SA? Mind sharing the code? Or enable SQL statement loggging (`engine.echo = True`) when doing so in order to see what `INSERT` statements are generated.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, Sorry, I'm not following you. Are you saying this is just a "printing" issue and I can use `ROUND` to see additional digits?

Comment: @ACV It's just an educated guess (I do not use MySQL personally lately) but it appears that all your values were printed with **exactly six digits** (except two where the sixth was `.0` so it was left off), and I think based on your `CREATE TABLE` statement the internal representation should be quite a bit longer. I'm wondering if you would get different results using, e.g., `ROUND(mjd, 3)`.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist @#*$&%#*$, you were right. If you want to submit and answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @ACV OK, as requested :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all your values were printed with exactly six digits (except where `.0` was left off in a couple of places). While I can't find any documentation on this, I suspect this is simply a default MySQL behavior for displaying `float` values in the context of a `SELECT` statement.

Based on the `CREATE TABLE` statement you provided, the internal representation is correct, so you need only add something like `ROUND(mjd, 3)` to your statement, with the first argument being the fields to round and the last being the number of digits to round to (which can be **longer** than what is displaying now).